# Tabula-py for borderless table extraction

Tags: python-3.x, pdftotext, tabula

Can anyone please suggest me how to extract tabular data from a PDF using python/java program for the below borderless table present in a pdf file?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This table might be difficult one for tabla. How about using `guess=False, stream=True` ?

Update: As of tabula-py 1.0.3, `guess` and `stream` should work together. No need to set `guess=False` to use `stream` or `lattice` option.

Comment: Hi @chezou Thanks you for your comment. I tried your answer with the below code
`tabula.convert_into("/Downloads/Test_Invoices/Invoice4.pdf",
                    "/Downloads/Test_Invoices/Invoice4.csv", output_format="csv",spreadsheets=True,guess=False, stream=True)
`

But no table has been extracted

Comment: Hi @chezou , Any other Python/Java related libraries you know?

Comment: I recommend you to set `pages` option. By default, tabula-py sets 1.

Comment: Hi @chezou , how would i do that? I'm not quite familiar with specifying these parameter values..

Comment: **Here's my code**

`df = tabula.read_pdf("/Downloads/Invoice1.pdf",guess=False, stream=True)
print(df)`

Comment: set `pages="all"` lor `pages=2` for `read_pdf()` or `convert_into()`. For future detail, it’d be nice you to read the manual https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py/blob/master/README.md or you can check test codes https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py/blob/master/tests/test_read_pdf_table.py

Comment: Thanks for your update, I updated my code and went through the docs as you mentioned, but no hope in extracting it. Its alright i'm working on Python's **invoice2Data** code on Github and its helping a bit. Just need to make this process automated.
Thanks a lot for your application. Its great..!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem via `tabula-py`

```
conda install tabula-py
```

and

```
>>> import tabula
>>> area = [70, 30, 750, 570] # Seems to have to be done manually
>>> page2 = tabula.read_pdf("nar_2021_editorial-2.pdf", guess=False, lattice=False, 
                 stream=True, multiple_tables=False, area=area, pages="all",
                   ) # `tabula` doc explains params very well
>>> page2
```

and I got this result

```
> 'pages' argument isn't specified.Will extract only from page 1 by default. [      
> ShortTitle                                              Text  \  0    
> Arena3Dweb         3D visualisation of multilayered networks     1    
> Aviator       Monitoring the availability of web services     2       
> b2bTools  Predictions for protein biophysical features and     3      
> NaN                                their conservation     4         
> BENZ WS          Four-level Enzyme Commission (EC) number     ..      
> ...                                               ...     68 
> miRTargetLink2              miRNA target gene and target pathway    
> 69             NaN                                          networks  
> 70       mmCSM-PPI            Effects of multiple point mutations on  
> 71             NaN                      protein-protein interactions  
> 72        ModFOLD8           Quality estimates for 3D protein models  
> 
>  
>                                                 URL    0                    http://bib.fleming.gr/Arena3D    1         
> https://www.ccb.uni-saarland.de/aviator    2                   
> https://bio2byte.be/b2btools/    3                                    
> NaN    4                 https://benzdb.biocomp.unibo.it/    ..       
> ...    68  https://www.ccb.uni-saarland.de/mirtargetlink2    69       
> NaN    70          http://biosig.unimelb.edu.au/mmcsm ppi    71       
> NaN    72       https://www.reading.ac.uk/bioinf/ModFOLD/      [73
> rows x 3 columns]]
```

This is an iterable obj, so you can manipulate it via `for row in page2:`

Hope it help you

Answer (score 0):

**Tabula-py borderless table extraction:**

Tabula-py has **stream** which on True detects table based on gaping.

```
from tabula convert_into
src_pdf = r"src_path"
des_csv = r"des_path"
convert_into(src_pdf, des_csv, guess=False, lattice=False, stream=True, pages="all")
```